# How to test a sql injection in php to check the over website in secure with injection or not?

Tags: sql, testing, code-injection

I developed a website in php using CI Framework.  I just want to check that my website is secure or not. I want to test apply sql injection on that.

Comment: Did you try injecting any sql?

Comment: What is preventing you from doing this?

Comment: You should be able to find a script fairly quick if you google for it.  Put that into your username and password text box to test it out.

Comment: no didn't tried any SQL injection i don't how that's work or how to make a sql injection for testing purpose.